# How to extract a Graph[] from an image?

Tags: graphs-and-networks

This graph (as a picture) is given below:

[image: my graph]

I am wondering rather than setting up this network graph using Mathematica syntax such as `PathGraph`,`Graph`, ect, is there a convenient way to ask Mathematica to interpret this itself?
So I can apply some functions from [this link](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/GraphsAndNetworks.html).

Comment: I'm sure one could use image processing, text recognition, and some syntax analysis to "automatically" convert this image into traditional Graph format, but it will be much simpler to code it by hand.

Comment: Try a Python tool? http://nefi.mpi-inf.mpg.de/index.html

Comment: @DavidG.Stork unless you have 100 or more to translate :)

Comment: All your graphs are undirected, I hope...

Comment: `MorphologicalGraph` may be a starting point, but it doesn't exactly do the same thing.  As I understand it is looking for branch points.  The Python library @Ian linked appears to do the same.  This means that graphs such as `Graph[{1 <-> 2, 2<-> 3}]` (i.e. no branch points) won't be easy to handle.

Answer (score 7):

```
i      = RemoveAlphaChannel@Import@"https://i.stack.imgur.com/k8KCQ.png";
cs     = ColorSeparate@i;
vxs    = Binarize@ImageSubtract[cs[[1]], cs[[2]]];
vxPos  = ComponentMeasurements[vxs, "Centroid"][[All, 2]];
rad    = ComponentMeasurements[vxs, "EquivalentDiskRadius"][[All, 2]] // Mean // Ceiling;
graph  = SelectComponents[ColorNegate@Binarize@i, "Area", -1];
edges  = ImageSubtract[graph, Dilation[vxs, rad/2]];
edges1 = Image@MorphologicalComponents[edges, CornerNeighbors -> False];
endpts = MorphologicalTransform[Binarize@SkeletonTransform@Binarize@edges1, "EndPoints"];
id     = ImageData[edges1] ImageData[endpts];
f      = Nearest[vxPos -> Range@Length@vxPos];
edgesnums = Rest@Union@Flatten@id;
ivp    = ImageValuePositions[Image@id, #] & /@ edgesnums;
ed     = UndirectedEdge @@@ Union @@@ Map[f, ivp, {2}]; 
GraphicsRow[{i, 
            Graph[ed, VertexCoordinates -> vxPos, 
                      VertexShapeFunction -> "Circle", VertexSize -> 0.2, 
                      VertexStyle -> Red]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]